Do CosmosDB Emulator Containers have large partition keys enabled by default?
I'm creating a container with default options, in a local CosmosDB Emulator, using .NET SDK v3. When looking at container settings, I see Large Partition Keys is enabled:
container settings screenshot
However, from LargePartitionKey Docs, Large Partition Keys should be disabled by default when creating containers through the .NET SDK.
Seems like a differing behavior from Cloud product to Emulator, that is not mentioned in Emulator docs. Can anyone confirm?


However, from LargePartitionKey Docs, Large Partition Keys should be disabled by default when creating containers through the .NET SDK.

The documentation you linked says:

By default, all containers created using the .NET SDK V2 do not support large partition keys. By default, all containers created using the .NET SDK V3 support large partition keys.

V3 created containers support Large Partition Keys, V2 created containers are the ones that do not support it.
